# javascript filter method with a conditional

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Would like to know if there is a way to use the *filter* method with a condition inside, so in that case, the color cannot be black, therefore the object with the label and value black won't be returned. The code below It's not working as expected...

```
function mapColors ({ colors } = colorsConfig) {
  return colors.filter(color => ({
    label: color.text !== 'black',
    value: color.text !== 'black'
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the Array.filter() method, you need to pass a callback to this method that returns either true or false, but your example returns an object. To do what you want to achieve I'd change it to:

```
return colors.filter(color => (color.text !== 'black'))
```

Comment: Your solution looks pretty cool, but I would like to know how I can return an array of objects with *label* and *value* values for each color

Comment: You could add .map then to the result of the filter, these things are chainable since they all return arrays, so if you want an object with a label and value I'd go:

    return colors.filter(color => (color.text !== 'black')).map(color => ({ label: '', value: ''}))

Then just fill label and value with what you want from the color argument

Comment: Cool, I just made .......map(color => ({ label: color.text, value: color.text}))
WORKS!

Comment: Nice :) glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Filter expects you to return a boolean

```
function mapColors ({ colors } = colorsConfig) {
  return colors.filter(color => color.label !='black' && color.value!='black');
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check `text` and get only non black items.

```
function mapColors ({ colors } = colorsConfig) {
    return colors.filter(({ text } => text !== 'black');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a callback function to filter

```
function mapColors ({ colors } = colorsConfig) {
    return colors.filter(color => {
        return color.text !== 'black' && color.label !== 'black'
    })
}
```